# Как построить горизонтальную таблицу из запросов mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

нужно построить аналитическую таблицу построенную на данных из огромной mysql базы.Из того что удалось решить это реализация горизонтальной прокрутки но застрял на выводе данных так как колонки повторяються и меняеться только дата.Для понимания выкладываю скрин,в таблицу планируеться выводить колонки-число-изделие-количество-следующее число и тд.Не прошу писать код, хотя бы просто укажите к какую сторону смотреть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так выглядит верстка при использовании масивов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю скрины из редактора, да я прекрасно понимаю что код кривой и написан рукожопом но именно что бы это исправить и спрашиваю совета у Вас

```html
<div class="mainp">Главная</div> <br> <a href="/enter.php?do=logout" class="button"/>Выход</a>
<hr />
<br>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
</head>
<style>
.search-table-outter {border:2px solid red; overflow-x:hidden;position:relative;}
.search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;}
.search-table, td, th{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;}
th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444; background:#66C2E0;}
td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
#w-scroll {position:absolute;width:100%;height:auto;overflow-x:scroll}
#w-scroll .scroll {height:1px;}
</style>
<body> 
<div class="search-table-outter wrapper">
 <table class="search-table inner">
  <thead>
<?php 
require 'connect.php';
$strSQL = "select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya`  and  date=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') LIMIT 1;";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo '
    <tr>
 <th>'.$row['date'].'</th>';}?>
      <th>Изделие</th>
      <th>Операция</th>
      <th>Количество</th> 
   <?php 
require 'connect.php';
$strSQL = "select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya`  and  date=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-02') LIMIT 1;";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo '
 <th>'.$row['date'].'</th>';}?>
      <th>Изделие</th>
      <th>Операция</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
require 'connect.php';
$strSQL = "select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya`  and  date=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01') order by detal desc;";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
echo '
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>'.$row['ch'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['translate'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['colvodetal'].'</td> ';}?>
   <?php 
require 'connect.php';
$strSQL = "select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya`  and  date=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-02') order by detal desc;";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
echo '
   <td>#</td>
      <td>'.$row['ch'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['translate'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['colvodetal'].'</td> </tr> ';}?>
   </table>
  </tbody>

</html>
```

а браузер это видит вот так

```html
<!doctype html>
<div class="mainp">Главная</div> <br> <a href="/enter.php?do=logout" class="button"/>Выход</a>
<hr />
<br>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">
</head>
<style>
.search-table-outter {border:2px solid red; overflow-x:hidden;position:relative;}
.search-table{table-layout: fixed; margin:40px auto 0px auto;}
.search-table, td, th{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;}
th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444; background:#66C2E0;}
td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
#w-scroll {position:absolute;width:100%;height:auto;overflow-x:scroll}
#w-scroll .scroll {height:1px;}
</style>
<body> 
<div class="search-table-outter wrapper">
 <table class="search-table inner">
  <thead>

    <tr>
 <th>2018-08-01 00:00:00.000000</th>      <th>Изделие</th>
      <th>Операция</th>
      <th>Количество</th> 
   
 <th>2018-08-02 00:00:00.000000</th>      <th>Изделие</th>
      <th>Операция</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Фитинг ST-FT-01-1</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>429</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Фитинг ST-FT-01-1</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>615</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>ОСЬ КО2.461</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>147</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>015</td>
   <td>40</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>015</td>
   <td>44</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>020</td>
   <td>63</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>020</td>
   <td>59</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>КЛАПАН КО2.451 </td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>149</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>КЛАПАН КО2.451 </td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>25</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>СЕДЛО ЗДШ35.02.001</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>40</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>СЕДЛО ЗДШ35.02.001</td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>63</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>СЕДЛО ЗДШ35.02.001</td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>40</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Головка НППН 611186.002-03</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>30</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Клапан В1-15х35.00.021</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>78</td> 
    <tr>
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Клапан В1-15х35.00.021</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>41</td>    
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Фитинг ST-FT-01-1</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>28</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Клетка НППН.306577.009.002</td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>16</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Клетка НППН.306577.009.002</td>
   <td>2 токарная</td>
   <td>36</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>ОСЬ КО2.461</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>203</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>ОСЬ КО2.461</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>224</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.04.001</td>
   <td>015</td>
   <td>66</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>015</td>
   <td>45</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>НИППЕЛЬ КП92.16.000</td>
   <td>020</td>
   <td>20</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Клапан В1-15х35.00.021</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>108</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Форсунка IZTT.05.02.004</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>570</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>Форсунка IZTT.05.02.004</td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>1050</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>ВАЛ ИЗВМ.001.016 </td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>500</td> </tr> 
   <td>#</td>
      <td>ВАЛ ИЗВМ.001.016 </td>
   <td>1 токарная</td>
   <td>500</td> </tr>    </table>
  </tbody>

</html>
```

Comment: Считайте данные в массив, где ключом служит дата. После этого в цикле заполняете каждый день. Вёрстку подсказать не смогу. Зависит от многих факторов

Comment: именно так и делал,но столкнулся с проблемой что не адекватно строит таблицу каждый новый день уезджает вниз.Но благодарю за ответ буду пробовать еще

Comment: Покажите что и куда уезжает и как вы хотите чтобы было.

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил скрин в пост

Comment: А у вас имеются все записи для второй даты?

Comment: @Anamnian записи имеються в диапазоне год- два, php составляющая кода работает отмено, и все выводиться проблемма именно в том что при выводе в таблицу записи "уплывают" без видимой причины

Comment: @freakrock я имел ввиду в данных которые вам sql возвращает есть все записи для второй даты на приведенном скрине? Можете привести данные которые вам отдает mysql?

Comment: @Anamnian что за первый что за второй день выводяться запросом select * from `cena` left join `cnc` on `cena`.`cher` = `cnc`.`detal` left join `chertesh` on `cnc`.`detal`=`chertesh`.`id` WHERE `cena`.`operaciya` = `cnc`.`operaciya`  and  date=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-02')   меняеться просто число в

Comment: А теперь приведите в вопросе html разметку, которая у вас получилась на скрине

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил скрины в пост

Comment: Мне не нужен ваш код. Мне нужен html, который у вас получился на уже сгенерированной странице.

Comment: @ArchDemon если правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то обновил пост

Comment: Мне нужна не картинка, а html разметка того, что на картинке. Вот этот html и вставьте в вопрос

Comment: @ArchDemon добавленно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь, решил задачу старым как мир трюком, созданием таблицы в таблице и все заработало именно так как нужно
Пример :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

        <table>
          <tr><td>ТАБЛИЦА СЛЕВА</td></tr>
        </table>


    </td>

    <td>

        <table>
          <tr><td>ТАБЛИЦА СПРАВА</td></tr>
        </table>


    </td>
    <td>

        <table>
          <tr><td>ЕЩЕ ПРАВЕЕ, и так 31 таблица в ряд</td></tr>
        </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```